# Homemade fstat to get file size, always returns 0 length

Tags: c, file, file-io, binary, fseek

I am trying to use my own function to get the file size from a file. I'll use this to allocate memory for a data structure to hold the information on the file.

The file size function looks like this:

```
long fileSize(FILE *fp){
    long start;
    fflush(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    start = ftell(fp);
    return (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) - start);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
return (ftell(fp) - start);
```

instead of

```
return (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) - start);
```

because [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) return zero on success not the offset as you are expecting here.

Comment: Thank you. *I guess I should have spent some more time reading the man page. :)

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- don't call `fflush()` - your stream might be a read stream, for which `fflush()` results in undefined behaviour
- you don't have any error checking !
- `fseek()` returns 0 for success - you need to call `ftell()` to get the length

Change the code to this:

```
long fileSize(FILE *fp)
{    
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    return ftell(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ftell` after `fseek`. Try:

```
long fileSize(FILE *fp){
  long start;
  fflush(fp);
  rewind(fp);
  start = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
  return ftell(fp);
}
```

There's no need to do a difference, so your first `ftell` is useless and you can get rid of it. I would use:

```
long filezise(FILE *fp)
{
  fseek(fp,OL,SEEK_END);
  // fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); - only if you want to seek back to the beginning
  return ftell(fp);
}
```

Also, make sure you open your file in binary mode.

Comment: Thats great, I did not know you could do this. Thanks!